# ORA-01722: invalid number, olympics schema on oracle live

Tags: oracle

The SQL giving error in oracle live

```
        select a.athlete_name 
        from olym.olym_athletes a,
        olym.olym_athlete_games c
        where a.id=c.athlete_id
        and nation_id='MAS';
```

Error:-`ORA-01722: invalid number`

What I am trying to do here is display all the Malaysian Olympics athletes. I am using public schema from oracle live. I am not sure why I keep getting invalid number error here.

Details below:-

```
TABLE OLYM_ATHLETES

    Column  Null?   Type
    ID  NOT NULL    NUMBER
    ATHLETE_NAME    NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(255)
    ATHLETE_GENDER  NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(10)

TABLE OLYM_ATHLETE_GAMES
                Column  Null?   Type
                ID  NOT NULL    NUMBER
                ATHLETE_ID  NOT NULL    NUMBER
                GAME_ID NOT NULL    NUMBER
                NATION_ID   NOT NULL    NUMBER
```

Comment: Please post your query as a text and provide table definitions as a text. There's no way to guess column datatypes and what may be a number

Comment: Also post lines 1-20 of your script (again as **text** and not images). The error is probably from those lines and not from your query. (Oracle Live will re-run the entire script)

Comment: Most of the columns are numbers. I hope you are able to find which two columns/values has mismatched datatypes

Answer (score 0):

your nation_id is a number hence you can use olym_nations table to get the nation_id

```
    select a.athlete_name from olym.olym_athletes a, 
    olym.olym_nations b, olym.olym_athlete_games c where 
    a.id=c.athlete_id and c.nation_id=b.id and b.nation='MAS';
```